# VLC (snap installation) - allow access to custom path (custom interface)

Tags: permissions, vlc, snap

I installed VLC Media Player from snap and I'd like to access videos in custom path. I have a directory in root (`/mydirectory`) with a few mounted NFS shares (`/mydirectory/nfs0`, `/mydirectory/nfs0`, and so on...).

Based on my understanding I need to a create custom interface similar to interface "home" and plug VLC into this custom interface.

Could you please let me know how to do it?

I cannot find anything like this anywhere in snap documentation...

---

**edit**
this is not a duplicate question of: [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap)

In the question above the fix is simple - you can connect the snap (your desired application) into existing interface "removable-media".

I'm asking about creating **custom interface** for **custom path**.

Can you help me with that please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give snaps access to /somedir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir)

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems that this is not possible with snaps. You probably can do it as a developer for your own snap but not as a user.