# Is it possible to update Snap Bitcoin-Core datadir to NFS mount point under /media?

Tags: snap, automount, nfs, bitcoin

I couldn't find anything specific regarding NFS storage in `/media` for bitcoin-core snap on Ubuntu.

From what I could gather with limited understanding is that only `/home` and `/media` folders on host system are available to Snap.

1. However, it seems that each snap needs to be enabled to be able to connect to host file system?

   Using VLC snap as an example, it has a connection plug that is configured with slot :home

   ```
   $ sudo snap connections vlc

   Interface               Plug                        Slot                     Notes
   audio-playback          vlc:audio-playback          :audio-playback          -
   audio-record            vlc:audio-record            -                        -
   camera                  vlc:camera                  -                        -
   desktop                 vlc:desktop                 :desktop                 -
   desktop-legacy          vlc:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy          -
   dvb                     vlc:dvb                     -                        -
   **home                    vlc:home                    :home                    -**
   ....... (others removed)
   ```

   Then looking at Bitcoin-core Snap 19.1 version, there is no plug for Home as is the case with VLC.

   ```
   $ sudo snap connections bitcoin-core 

   Interface     Plug                       Slot  Notes
   desktop       bitcoin-core:desktop       -     -
   network       bitcoin-core:network       -     -
   network-bind  bitcoin-core:network-bind  -     -
   x11           bitcoin-core:x11           -     -
   ```

   Based on [How to give snaps access to /somedir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir), `/home` and `/media` should be working with snap.

   I'm using AutoMaster to mount my NFS shared on `` /media/nfs/myshares` ``

   From the host system, I can browse to all my NFS shares
2. Does that mean that as bitcoin-core snap doesn't have plug for home that it will essentially not be possible to update the bitcoin datadir to `/media/nfs/bitcoin` where I have enough space to host the full bitcoin database?

Details regarding snap install

```
$ sudo snap version

snap    2.44.3+20.04
snapd   2.44.3+20.04
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-33-generic
```

Details of Bitcoin-Core snap installed

```
$ sudo snap list

Name                  Version                     Rev   Tracking         Publisher     Notes
bitcoin-core          0.19.1                      63    latest/stable    bitcoin-core  -
```