# Add mounts/symlinks into snap automatically

Tags: mount, snap, symbolic-link

I use several symlinks in my root directory usually pointing somewhere into /home directory. I can keep projects organized in directories, but I still have quick (terminal) access to them.

e.g.:
`/g -> /home/z/projects/kotlin/TheGame`

But for snap applications, these symlinks are not visible.

Does exist any way how to globally add such symlinks (/bind mounts/another solution) to snap applications?

Thanks

Comment: I can understand why you may want such links for data directories (but why in the root file system???), but not why you would want this for applications. These can be summoned already by a single command, which you could further abbreviate with a symbolic link or an alias. For daily use, you have no business in the application folders.

Comment: @vanadium `cd /g` is shorter `cd /home/z/g` and `cd ~/g` does not work under root user. When I have "/g/image.png" in clipboard, I cannot open such image in snap gimp for example and I have to retype the path.

Comment: It is a very bad habbit to run user applications as root user.

Comment: Running as root is only one of usecases which does not cause problems. Main issue is about snap apps which cannot access the path.

Comment: Probably not easy to solve: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir