# How to run snap installed programs as different users & groups?

Tags: permissions, snap

Is there something where I can change the user/group id of Snap installed applications?
I would like to secure what folders/files they have access to on my machine.

Similar to

```
sudo -H -u "$USER" -g "$GROUP" /bin/command
```

or like systemd

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=john
Group=admins
ExecStart=/bin/command
TimeoutStartSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give snaps access to /somedir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir)

Comment: No, I more-so want to block off part of my system incase the application was breached remotely.

Comment: Snaps are designed to be sandboxed/secured by default, and without connections, cannot reach anything. So perhaps indicate more clearly and specifically  what your really want to achieve. Further increase security of snaps?

Comment: I'm under the impression some applications can be fuzzed remotely where code is written to ram to create a shell... if an application starts with a certain uid and the shell is created.. It will be stuck with that uid.. Making it an extra challenge for the attacker to gain root. -- But maybe snap is secure enough?

Comment: Snap applications are supervised by AppArmor, which has a list of rules  (permitted actions) for each application included with the Snap. AppArmor will override and deny actions that are not on the list, including launching other applications -- including shells. If you discover any loopholes in the AppArmor  supervision of a particular Snap, or if you discover a bug in AppArmor, or if you discover any application that can be exploited to gain remote access, please report it to the appropriate bug tracker! For folks interested in security, I recommend https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/