# snap firefox can't open url when started within a nfs-shared-directory

Tags: firefox, snap, nfs

I installed firefox via `snap install firefox`

I went to my Downloads folder: `cd ~/Downloads/` and executed:

```
firefox "www.duckduckgo.com"
```

firefox opens with the website duckduckgo.

Than I went to my nfs-share: `cd /mnt/my-nfs-share/` and executed the same command:

```
firefox "www.duckduckgo.com"
```

I got following error:

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

If I install firefox via `apt install firefox` everything works as usually.

- I'm new to snaps (and kind a like them) but how can I give the correct permission to it and why do I need to this by myself?
- Is there a "bug" in the snap-configuration?

Comment: *snap* packages run confined (*higher security*) and they don't have full access to your whole file-system having access to $HOME or your user directory; and only limited other directories if permitted (which do include `/mnt` & `/media` but not at snap startup).  You're requesting access at startup where only $HOME is allowed; your issue is close to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1832711 but I can confirm still exists in *kinetic* - but you cannot access `/mnt` or `/media` at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*snap* packages run confined (*higher security*) and they don't have full access to your whole file-system having access to $HOME or your user directory; and only limited other directories if permitted (which do include `/mnt` & `/media` but not at snap startup).

You're requesting access at startup where only $HOME is allowed; you didn't provide release details, but I'm getting the same with my *kinetic* box (the issue issue reminds me of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1832711 but description won't match, is not chromium-browser based but all snaps & exists in *kinetic*).

You cannot access `/mnt` or `/media` at snap startup.

---

I had a brief discussion with *ogra* (*Oliver Grawert*) who said to file a bug... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1989156

Comment: I'll likely amend this answer... I had a brief discussion with *ogra* (Oliver Grawert) who said to file a bug... I'll do that..

Comment: Ah thanks! I tried to fix it by changing my mount-point to the home-directory. This dosn't work because he dosn't has access to the whole mounted directory-tree (only to the first level). The Idea of chaning mount-points I got from this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir