# Gnome Boxes unable to run virtual machine: Permission denied

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, snap-store, gnome-boxes

I installed *Gnome Boxes* via *Ubuntu Software Center*, choose source: *Snap Store* latest/stable version `42.0.1-5-ga2f71278db`. When I tried to run existing `*.qcow2` image I get an error: `Failed to start!`. The same error with creating new virtual machine.

Here the logs:

```
$ snap run gnome-boxes
(gnome-boxes:40467): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:48:20.627: GtkListBox with a model will ignore sort and filter functions
Boxes-Message: 13:48:20.971: libvirt-machine.vala:259: Failed to connection to system libvirt: Unable to open qemu+unix:///system: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock-ro': Permission denied
```

As well I get permission denied when I try to open `/media` directory
BTW: version `3.36.5-0ubuntu2` that was installed via `apt install gnome-boxes` is working well without any issues

OS: *Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS x86_64*

Comment: In general, snap is a sandboxed system. Each app is isolated. They don't have access to anything outside their snap environment.

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1429493/edit) and add the information about Ubuntu version in your question. The comments are mainly for us to ask you for clarification and provide you information.

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir).