# Docker volume not properly mounted

Tags: mount, snap, docker

My `docker-compose.yml` (for Immich, in case it's important) contains this:

```
volumes:
  - ${UPLOAD_LOCATION}:/usr/src/app/upload
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  - /data/NAS_Photos:/mnt/NAS_Photos:ro   # <-- The one I'm having trouble with
```

The intention (for the avoidance of doubt) is to make `/data/NAS_Photos` from my host available inside the container at `/mnt/NAS_Photos`.

When I `docker-compose up -d` the relevant container has a directory `/mnt/NAS_Photos` but `mount | grep -i mnt` shows

```
none on /mnt/NAS_Photos type tmpfs (ro,relatime,inode64)
```

Additionally the directory is almost empty. It does not contain the contents of my `/data/NAS_Photos`. (It does contain a few leftover files from previous attempts to debug this, and if I move the mount to a different location inside the container the leftover files appear there too. These files persist if I `docker compose down` and `docker compose up`.)

Why would this not be mounted, or, how can I debug why it isn't mounted? No error messages are given that I can see.

Using Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS.

What I have checked:

- `/data` is owned by my user, and permissions on it, and `/data/NAS_Photos` are both 777.
- I can mount a directory in the same location as the `docker-compose.yml` without a problem.
- The output of `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' immich_microservices` is:

  `[{bind  /home/mark/Immich/library /usr/src/app/upload  rw true rprivate} {bind  /etc/localtime /etc/localtime  ro false rprivate} {bind  /data/NAS_Photos /mnt/NAS_Photos  ro false rprivate}]`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be with Snapd, of all things.

Docker was installed as a Snap, and Snaps have limited access to the host filesystem (discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir)). My media was in a directory not accessible by Snaps, and therefore Docker (installed as a snap) could not see it.

My (somewhat hacky) workaround was to bind-mount the media into my home directory.

Comment: Interesting. I would advice you to install Docker from the repos instead, so nice I believe snap limitations aren't well suited for Docker use.