Firefox snap won't save websites
After changing to Ubuntu 24.04.1 Firefox was installed via snap. This Firefox will not save complete HTML websites. Older saved websites from a backup cannot be read. Firefox will not find these files. Firefox uses strange paths like run/user/1000/doc/bigNumber/downloads instead of /data/downloads which is configured in about:config. Downloading seems to work if I use a download-path within the /home-tree.

This appears to be a known issue by Mozilla. See this Mozilla Support article for a fix

since snaps are a Canonical thing, you may need to report this as a bug (or join in any bug already posted)

/data/downloads is a location snaps cannot access. If this is the mountpoint for a partition, use a different mountpoint under /media instead, e.g. /media/data, change the firefox config accordingly and grant your snap permission to access removable media.

Snap packages are confined by default.
Snap applications cannot access anything outside your /home directory. They cannot access /data.
You can move your data into /home
Or you can bind-mount your /data into a /home location
Or you can use a mounting location that is permitted (/home, /media)
Or you can use a separate process to sync /data with a permitted location.
Or you can use a non-snap version of the application.

Related (bind-mounting stuff under ~ to make it accessible to snaps): https://askubuntu.com/a/1384789/380067

Thanks for the answers. Problem solved by deinstalling Firefox snap and installing the original Mozilla deb-Package. I need to view many 'html-files' (e.g. 'javadoc' files as documentation of progs and libraries which are to be found within /data); so the browser has to show these files too , in a different partition /data which is on an second disk, not within the /home or /media tree.
