# Multiple Instances of /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"

Tags: 18.10, squashfs

I am having real troubles sorting this out!

[image]

Why is the blkid output flooded with so many instances of **/dev/loopx: TYPE="squashfs"**?

No significant information is available on the internet!

Any help would be really appreciated.

Abbas.

Comment: Sorry, but these posts do not address my issue! Or, at least, I am unable to find any similarities! Please note I would not call myself an expert in this!

Comment: The point is that recent versions of Ubuntu use _snaps_ to install some applications. Simply said, these _snaps_ run in a confined environment and cannot access the rest of your system. A "downside" of this is that each _snap_ requires a filesystem on its own (of type `squashfs`) and that is what you see when you run `lsblk` or `df`. Further reading [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/808524/504066) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)).

Comment: Thank you PerlDuck. I do understand that! But why do all the instances have the same comment (Type ="squashfs")?

Comment: That's not a _comment_ but the filesystem's _type_. Like NTFS, ext4, FAT, and so on. `squashfs` is just another _type_ (although I don't know the particulars of that filesystem).

Comment: Ohh kkk! Thank you very much for the clarification.