# How to uninstall GitKraken

Tags: 18.04, uninstall

I want to uninstall GitKraken but it does not show up in Ubuntu software center and I can't find it in terminal using the command `dpkg --list` on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

What else can I do to uninstall Gitkraken??

Comment: `sudo apt --purge remove gitkraken` did the trick for me..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu is slowly moving towards snaps. So, sometimes it becomes a little bit difficult to guess whether a package installed from Ubuntu Software is a deb package or a snap package. Also, it is to be noted that some packages are available via snap as well as apt, thus Software Center can have two entries for identical apps. It's better to look at the bottom of app in Software Center to identify whether it is a snap package or a package installed via apt. For example, here GitKraken, it is only available via Snap, since `apt search gitkraken` returned no results and looking at the bottom of app page:

[image]

Also, `dpkg` is a tool for managing deb packages and apt is a front end for dpkg. That's why you can't find GitKraken in `dpkg --list`.

To list currently installed snap:

```
snap list
```

To uninstall snap:

```
sudo snap remove snap_name
```

If you want to install a deb package of GitKraken, you can download it from [here](https://release.axocdn.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb) and install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i gitkraken-amd64.deb
```

If you want to know more about snaps:

- [Why is Ubuntu moving to Snappy packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/618471/816190)
- [Why are there some packages in the Software application but not in apt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1087104/816190)
- [If a package is available as both a deb and a snap, which method is preferrable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029610/816190)
- [Why are there 2 packages for some applications (e.g. Chromium) in Ubuntu Software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/972411/816190)

Comment: 'snap list' doesn't list 'gitkraken' as of today. Wondering what is the new way to remove it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you're installing it via ubuntu software center which is using snap packages, just execute this `snap remove gitkraken`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I installed it via download of gitkraken-amd64.deb.
Snap didn't worked for me.

I could find it:

1. `ls -la $(which gitkraken)`

and

2. `dpkg -L gitkraken`

and removed it with:

```
sudo dpkg -P gitkraken
```