# Netflix, Amazon Prime, and Other DRM Content

Tags: firefox, drm

I am curious, how come when I install the Official Mozilla Snap from the Ubuntu Software store on Ubuntu 18.04.3, I can watch DRM content, but when I use the build that comes with Ubuntu I can't watch DRM content even AFTER enabling it in Firefox?

I am using Firefox 70.0.1 on both versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences between how software is packaged and distributed when comparing snaps with traditional Debian packages (like those in Ubuntu repositories)

A **snap** is a universal Linux package that bundles the app with all of its dependencies.  Snaps are also container-like, being somewhat isolated from the base system.

When you install a package from Ubuntu repositories via `apt` or the GUI package manager, you are installing a standalone package (although the package manager will generally resolve required dependencies for you).

The Google Widevine HTML5 DRM decoder is not automatically included in the `firefox` package in Ubuntu repositories.  It can be installed as a plugin, which will allow decoding of HTML5 DRM content (the type of DRM used by Netflix) .

To the question as to ***why*** the snap might include it likely has to do with a few things:

The source code for Widevine is not publicly available and does not have a copy-left license.  Firefox is currently in the `main` Ubuntu repository, which is for open source software only.

Snaps are also somewhat isolated from the rest of your system, so including "potentially dangerous" proprietary software in a snap poses less of a risk.

Snaps are intended to be all-encompassing, without needing additional software, so the developers/publishers of the snap have likely decided to include HTML5 DRM support by default.

[Read more about snaps here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618471/why-is-ubuntu-moving-to-snappy-packages/)

Comment: great answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a Chromium plugin which allows me to play DRM video right away.

Install IdeaNova DRM Extension. In the Netherlands, where I live, our national broadcast company, NPO, provides only DRM video.  I was installing Ubuntu for a friend. I thought I had adjusted and personalized everything when I noticed I can't play NPO video! Bummer! But for now it works and I hope the plugin keeps up to date!

[IdeaNova](https://www.ideanovatech.com/)