# Questions about boot partition, EFI partition, and Swap in recent Ubuntu versions

Tags: partitioning

My last version of ubuntu was 16 but now its a mess. Is there a printed
manual on all this (expletives) new stuff?

I like to have a system partition then a data partition in case the
system gets trashed and for Samba. So i usually use a 20gig for system
and the rest for data. But now you cant even get an install with out
gripe gripe gripe. Used to just need a swap and system partitions.

1. What is a boot partition? Why doesnt it say minimum size?
2. What is an EFI partition?  Size again?
3. What no swap partition?
4. what is snap?

why does it keep griping thunderbird cant save a draft? ubuntu used to
just run.

Linux used to just run. Now its a nightmare for use and maintenance with
all the fancy stuff. hundreds of processes running in the background you
may never use.

Comment: `Linux used to just run. Now its a nightmare for use and maintenance with all the fancy stuff. ?` --- Ubuntu is not the very beginner friendly distribution it used to be. Canonical is focusing mostly on IoT and servers, and as a result, the Desktop Ubuntu does not have the polish it used to have. I personally recommend new users (and users who don't want to tinker a lot) move to Linux Mint.

Comment: `why does it keep griping thunderbird cant save a draft?` - Can you please ask a new question about this issue, with more details about the version of Ubuntu and the version of Thunderbird?

Comment: _"why does it keep griping thunderbird cant save a draft?"_ - Is your system partition full?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a printed manual on all this (expletives) new stuff?

No. However, if you have a specific question, feel free to ask on this site. Please ask a single question per post. You can ask multiple questions in a single post if they are very related, but if they are different questions, please ask in different posts.

> What is a boot partition? Why doesnt it say minimum size? What is an EFI partition? Size again?

The EFI partition is necessary to boot UEFI systems, but it is not necessary if you have an older BIOS system (which were present in all computers before the Windows 8 era). 512 MB is usually good enough.

A boot partition is necessary if you want full-disc encryption. It is also necessary if your computer cannot see boot files far from the start of the disc. For such computers, a boot partition (512 MB to 1GB) would be necessary.

If you have an older BIOS system, then just having a system partition (and optionally other partitions for storing data) should be adequate. A separate swap partition is not necessary (see below), but you can also use it if you have it and want to use it.

> What no swap partition?

In recent versions, Ubuntu uses a swapfile. No swap partition is necessary. But if you already have a swap partition, you can still use it. Just configure that partition to be used as a swap partition during installation.

> What is snap?

Snap is a package management system, similar to APT. See [Why is Ubuntu moving to Snap packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/618471/124466) for more details. Please be aware that snap packages are slower than their deb/apt counterparts in older computers without SSD, and also have a lot of bugs like unable to access user files.

Nowadays, Ubuntu packages Firefox and Chromium as snap (not pure APT) packages.
If you want to use firefox without snap, see [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)

> So i usually use a 20gig

Currently, the minimum recommended system partition size is 25 GB. However, you will need at least 40-50 GB or so in the system partition to comfortably use Ubuntu, especially if you install a lot of programs.

Comment: Do not  confuse a /boot partition which must be Linux formatted and often used with Servers or LVM type install with an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot which must be FAT32 with boot,esp flags. New installs now use a swap file, but if you have a swap partition, it will be used. Some suggest a swap partition of 4.1GB is better than default swap file of 2GB. If using Ubuntu and snaps, you need a large / (root) of 40 or 60GB. I use Kubuntu, do not allow any snaps and use about 16GB with all data in separate partition. But saw one user with 20GB of just snap apps

Comment: @marcelm I have edited the answer